# Need help to write a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-date-functions

I need to write a query to get tenure of assignment to a specific project.

I have a table of daily activities which stores data about everyone in a company and their allocation to a project in the below format.

[image: Refer attached image for table format]

This shows employee E123's allocation on various projects on each day.

The query should return start date and end date when the employee was not allocated. 
E.g. in above case, it should return

[image: Attached image2]

Grouping by projects returns only one record with start date 21-Jun-2019 and end date 27-Jun-2019 and tenure of 7 days which is wrong.

Tried this one:

```
select EmpCode, ProjectId, min(Date), max(Date), count(EmpCode)
where Date between cast('2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime) and getdate() --and s.ProjectId = 0
        and EmpId = 'E123'
group by EmpCode, ProjectId, Date
```

Comment: *"I need to write a query to get tenure of assignment to a specific project."* Great! Thanks for telling us and good luck. If you get stuck then please do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57671494/edit) you're post to be a question, and include your attempt(s) so that we can help you. If you find the answer, then perhaps consider posting it as the answer.

Comment: @Larnu, did not get you. You have a solution on this?

Comment: It looks like a "gaps and isnland" problem @VnA. You haven't asked a question here though; just made a request that we solve this problem for you. Stack Overflow is **not** a free coding service, it's a Q&A website for programming questions. If you have a question (These end in a "?"), please do ask one by editing your post, but ensure you show your attempt(s) in the question so that we can explain where you went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: yes we have the ans, but first try yourself anything, and edit this post if you stuck in your query somewhere.

Comment: As I said, I tried group by project (edited in the original question) but this does not give me break up in terms of date, it returns me collective result. Can you give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
    (
    EmpId nVARCHAR(8),
    ProjectId nVARCHAR(3),
    Date DATE
    )

INSERT INTO @Data
(EmpId, ProjectId, Date)
VALUES
('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-18'),
('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-19'),
('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-20'),
('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-21'),
('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-22'),
('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-23'),
('EMP123', 'P2', '2019-06-24'),
('EMP123', 'P2', '2019-06-25'),
('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-26'),
('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-27')

SELECT 
    MIN(d.Date) As StartDate,
    ISNULL(EndDate, MAX(Date)) As EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(d, MIN(d.Date), ISNULL(EndDate, MAX(Date))) + 1 As Tenure
FROM @Data d 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(d, -1, Date) As EndDate FROM @Data a WHERE a.EmpId = d.EmpId AND a.ProjectId IS NOT NULL AND a.Date > d.Date ORDER BY a.Date ASC) EndDate
WHERE
    d.ProjectId IS NULL
GROUP BY d.EmpId, d.ProjectId, EndDate
```

Comment: this worked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks for the help @Koen.

Answer (score 1):

A different (and more common) approach is creating islands (groups) using `ROW_NUMBER` and a CTE. This avoids a second scan of your data table. You can then group on the employee and the group to get your minimum and and maximum values:

```
DECLARE @Data table (EmpId char(6),
                     ProjectId char(2),
                     [Date] date);

INSERT INTO @Data (EmpId,
                   ProjectId,
                   Date)
VALUES ('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-18'),
       ('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-19'),
       ('EMP123', 'P1', '2019-06-20'),
       ('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-21'),
       ('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-22'),
       ('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-23'),
       ('EMP123', 'P2', '2019-06-24'),
       ('EMP123', 'P2', '2019-06-25'),
       ('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-26'),
       ('EMP123', NULL, '2019-06-27');

WITH Grps AS (
    SELECT D.EmpId,
           D.ProjectId,
           D.[Date],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.EmpId ORDER BY D.Date) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.EmpId, D.ProjectId ORDER BY D.Date) AS Grp
    FROM @Data D)
SELECT G.EmpId,
       MIN(G.[Date]) AS StartDate,
       MAX(G.[Date]) AS EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(G.[Date]),MAX(G.[Date]))+1 AS Tenure
FROM Grps G
WHERE G.ProjectId IS NULL
GROUP BY G.EmpId,
         G.Grp;
```

*(Thanks Koen Vissers, for consumable sample data.)*

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a relatively simple aggregation query to me.  The only challenge is identifying the groups.

However, that is also simple.  It is just the cumulative number of non-`NULL` `projectid` values:

```
select empid, min(date), max(date), count(*) as tenure
from (select d.*,
             count(projectid) over (partition by empid order by date) as grp
      from @data d
     ) d
where projectid is null
group by empid, grp
order by empid, min(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e1df4ded226ee2c0440d96c75684de1) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this >>

```
    SELECT EMP_PRO.EmpCode,
       EMP_PRO.ProjectId,
       Date_M.min_D StartDate,
       Date_M.max_D EndDate,
       Date_M.tenure
  FROM EMP_PRO
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT min (date) min_D, max (Date) max_D, count (Grp) tenure , ProjectId
          FROM (SELECT id,
                       ProjectId,
                       date,
                         DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY id)
                       - DENSE_RANK ()
                            OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY id)
                          AS Grp
                  FROM EMP_PRO) T
        GROUP BY T.Grp ,ProjectId) Date_M
          ON EMP_PRO.date = Date_M.min_D
 WHERE Date_M.min_D IS NOT NULL AND EMP_PRO.ProjectId IS NULL
```